# How to count up sec, min, hours and days in a proper way?

Tags: javascript, counter

I would like to write a counter, that counts me every sec, min, hour and day. It shouldn't start from 0 but from 2 min. For now I have the following code, but it doesn't seems to be right. I'm a beginner and trying to understand JS. Thanks in advance for your help and pations!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Counter</title>
    <script>
      start=new Date().getTime()-120000;
      function updateCounter() {
        var dif=new Date().getTime()-start;
        setTimeout(updateCounter, 1000-(dif%1000));
        var sec=Math.floor(dif/1000);
        var min=Math.floor(sec/60);
        var hou=Math.floor(min/60);
        var day=Math.floor(hou/24);
        sec %= 60;
        if (sec<10) {
          sec="0"+sec;
        }
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=day+":"+hou+":"+min+":"+sec;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="updateCounter();">
    <p id="counter"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about it _"doesn't seem to be right"_? From your description it seems like it works fine ([jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vntdcjy3/))

Comment: The problem is, that I have no idea how I can switch from 24 h to 1 day. Right now it counts 1day24h0m0sec. But it should be 1day0h0m0sec. Here is my code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't know that I can't put code into a reply of a comment. So here is my improved code. The problem is, that I have no idea how I can switch from 24 h to 1 day. Right now it counts 1day24h0m0sec. But it should be 1day0h0m0sec.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Counter</title>
    <script>
      var start=new Date().getTime()-86400000;
      function updateCounter() {
        var dif=new Date().getTime()-start;
        setTimeout(updateCounter, 1000-(dif%1000));
        var sec=Math.floor(dif/1000);
        var min=Math.floor(sec/60);
        var hou=Math.floor(min/60);
        var day=Math.floor(hou/24);
        sec %= 60;
        if (sec<10) {
          sec="0"+sec;
        }
        min %= 60;
        if (min<10) {
          min="0"+min;
        }
        hou %= 60;
        if (hou<10) {
          hou="0"+hou;
        }
        day %= 24;
        if (day<10) {
          day="0"+day;
        }
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=day+":"+hou+":"+min+":"+sec;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="updateCounter();">
    <p id="counter"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```